# Consuming parameters passed to your handlers - Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-12

Good morning, I am working with http.Controllers in odoo v.12, I want to pass the id through the url to get the following:

```
http://localhost:8069/my_library/book_details/1
```

The code I am using is:

```
from odoo import http

class Book(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/my_library/book_details/<model("library.book"):book>', type='http', auth='none')
    def book_details_in_path (self, book):
        print (book)
```

However I receive the following error message:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'RequestUID'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you define the type of [authentication method](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/http.html#routing) to `none`, The request code will not have any facilities to access the database nor have any configuration indicating the current database nor the current user.

In route definition, you called `model` which provides records directly when given their id and the authentication method used will not allow that.

To avoid this issue just change the authentication method.